# What does "the authors must present insightful implications based on their experimental outcomes" mean?

Tags: peer-review

I am advised to revise my paper about a novel clustering algorithm. From the responses of reviewers, I have this question:

> "the authors must present insightful implications based on their experimental outcomes."

I haven't understood what the reviewer means? Does he ask about a real case study, because I applied my algorithm only to benchmark of the UCI Machine Learning Repository? Available: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html.

Comment: what use is it? or maybe closer, what are the implications of your findings?

Comment: Seems like a question better suited for English.SE than here

Answer (score 18):

Without reading the paper and reports, I can only guess, but it sounds to me that they are asking "*Why do your experimental results matter? What do they tell us?*"

Comment: Yeah, that's how I read it too.  The referee just overdosed on buzzwords.